Seamless rectangle-to-circle transition in Blender
Having a hand in creating some product visualization exercises , I run into a bit of an issue or question mark if you'd like.
In more detail, Im trying to figure how one would go creating a half fillet to what appears (to my eyes) two shapes, a long vertical rectangle object with a circular extrusion at the top. Specifically the part Im having some issue optimizing is the fillet area between those two. (half left of the image)
Filleting  the join area(s) would obviously create issues with the fillet edge falling out of bounds of the shown shapes. I can think of many ways to get the desired shape, but interested in the "right way", path of least resistance.
Thanks for looking, if anything comes in mind would greatly appreciate your insight and experience.



Here is how I would do it quite easily, this will not be exactly the same as the reference, but maybe you can tweak the results to match it better to what you need. Of course you can always make it much more complicated and put more attention to detail, this is just for a quick but still good solution.
And for tweaking it is always good too have a not so highly detailed mesh - the less detail, the less vertices you have to handle afterwards. The rest will be done by a Subdivision Surface modifier. Your start is not bad, but I would have made it with less geometry.
I take a cylinder with only 12 vertices per loop, with two edge loops inbetween to separate the circular part from the later rectangular part and have one for the transition between them.

Then I select the bottom half face loop of what will be the rectangular part.

I extrude them down on the Z axis with E and afterwards scale them down to 0 on the Z axis to flatten them with S Z 0.

Then I select the lower inner vertices of the bottom half circle (not the outmost vertices).

I move them down a bit on the Z axis to have a slightly slanted transition between the rectangle and the circle.

Now I just add a Subdivision Surface modifier with a level of 2 to smoothen the surface.

Of course the rectangular part gets smoothed too much because of missing supporting edges. I could add some with the Loop Cut tool Ctrl+R like the ones shown selected below:

And this is the result, as I said not perfect but easy to do and still editable thanks to relatively few geometry:


Thanks for the reply and taking the time to provide screenshots. Yes, certainly that would be a way, even though as you pointed out not perfect - with a bit more geometry in place and edge loops it can get very close if not the same. Thank you once more
